# S3 bucket connection failed (HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When i am trying to image upload file to my s3 bucket via command line `aws s3 cp /Users/shravan40/Downloads/scan1.jpg s3://s3_bucket_name/access_key_id` it successfully uploads. But When i try to upload the image through Scala API then, it shows the Gateway timeout. I have set time out time as 2 minutes.

```
public void connect(){
    conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);        
}


public AmazonS3Client(AWSCredentials awsCredentials) {
    this(awsCredentials, new ClientConfiguration());
} 

public void setBucket(String bucketName){
    this.bucketName = bucketName;
    this.baseUrl = "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"+bucketName;
}
```

Here is the API code,

```
post("/api/:version/user/:id/image/upload") {
  CGMetrics.apiProfiler.profile("api.uploadImage") {
    val memberId: Long = params("id").toLong
    if (!AccountService.validateMemberId(memberId))
      APIResponseError(APIResponseCode.NOT_FOUND, "Invalid Member Id")
    else {
      val filePath: String = getUploadedFilePath("file_path", "file")
      val fileName: String = getParam("filename").get.toString

      if (filePath != null) {
        val (uploadImageUrl, resizedImageHeight, resizedImageWidth) = MediaService.uploadImage(memberId, 0, fileName, filePath)
        APIResponseOK(Map("imgUrl" -> uploadImageUrl, "imgHeight" -> resizedImageHeight, "imgWidth" -> resizedImageWidth))
      } else {
        APIResponseError(APIResponseCode.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, "No File Found")
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

And getUploadFilePath method,

```
private def getUploadedFilePath(filePathKey: String = "file_path", fieldName: String = "file")(implicit request: HttpServletRequest): String = {

val filePath: String = getParam(filePathKey) match {
  case Some(x) => x
  case None => fileParams.get(fieldName) match {
    case Some(file) =>

      val fileName = file.getName
      val ext = Helper.getFileExtension("/tmp/" + fileName)

      Log.logger(Log.FILE.DEFAULT).debug("file name = " + fileName)
      Log.logger(Log.FILE.DEFAULT).debug("file ext = " + ext)

      val tempFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "." + ext)
      Helper.writeToFile(tempFile, file.get())
      Log.logger(Log.FILE.DEFAULT).info("Created Temporary Asset : " + fileName + " at  " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath)

      tempFile.getAbsolutePath
    case None =>
      null
  }
}

filePath
}
```

**Update** : Now files are being uploaded to S3 bucket, but no confirmation for the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: accessing buckets is not done with the http protocol, but with the s3 protocol, eg. your bucket url should look something like `s3://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketName`. If you want to access it with http, you can enable static web hosting on your bucket.

Comment: @MartinHansen : I tried with s3://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketName , but response remain the same.

Comment: just use `s3://bucketName` (thats what i do) - i just copy pasted your solution and swapped http:// with the s3:// protocol as an example. I dont know the complete uri for your bucket :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with my method uplodImage, which was unable to get create thumbnail that's why i was getting time out.

And i was running reddis server on port 4381 but had provided the default port number i.e. 6397